# Cannot make Samsung ML2165 Printer work in Loki

Tags: release-loki, settings, printer

I have a Samsung ML2165 laser printer.  When I look at printers two are shown as follows:
Samsung ML-2160 Series
Samsung ML-2165

Both are shown as ready.

Nothing will print.  When I attempted to print a test page nothing happened, and an attempt to print a PDF also failed with a message that it was waiting for the printer.

I think I installed the ML2160 series driver when I had the PC at home and that Loki detected the ML 2165 when I connected it here on the boat in Turkey.
I think I probably need to delete the ML2160 series driver, and possibly both instances of the printer, and start again but how do I delete printers in Loki?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this problem.  I brought the printer back home to the UK and it failed to print when connected to my other mini PC running Loki at home.  It also failed to print when connected to a Windows PC, though it was detected and Windows automatically installed a driver for it.  The problem proved to be a faulty printer cable which apparently allowed the computers to see the printer but must have had one broken wire which prevented printing.  A different cable solved the problem.  Now I have to carry the printer back to Turkey!  The moral is always try a spare cable first.